# What functions are supported by CEC with Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one

I want to replace my Bluray player with an Xbox One, but I don't want to use the Xbox remote control all the time. Currently I control all functions of my Bluray player using the TV remote control. How well does this work with Xbox One?
Specifically:
Arrows, select, menu, FF, RW, etc.
And in which apps does it work? Bluray, Netflix, Hulu, Amazon, Audio CD, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Xbox One doesn't support HDMI CEC. All control of other devices by the Xbox One is done by the IR blaster, and there's no way to control the console except through a compatible controller, remote or Kinect.

Some guy actually went through the trouble of hooking a CEC analyzer to his Xbox One to prove that it doesn't support it: http://www.hometoys.com/emagazine/2013/12/the-xbox-one-currently-does-not-support-hdmi-cec/2218

An apparently open question is whether the Xbox One even has the hardware to support HDMI CEC. Special circuitry needs to be included to handle the CEC bus. If the Xbox one doesn't have this circuitry then CEC support can't be added to existing consoles by a firmware update.

Comment: Although the answer is correct. The XB1 does work the opposite way, you can use the xbox controller/remote to control everything, which may work for the asker's need (control everything with one device)

Comment: Apparently he doesn't "want to use the Xbox remote control all the time", but that's probably the only alternative to using multiple remotes.